# process_vm_readv() EFAULT

Tags: c, linux

I'm trying to create a child process and access its memory, but all my tests are leading to an `EFAULT` error.

```
#define _GNU_SOURCE // needed for process_vm_readv
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/uio.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(const int argc, char *const argv[]) {
    struct iovec local[2];
    struct iovec remote[1];
    char buf1[10];
    char buf2[10];
    ssize_t nread;
    pid_t pid; // PID of remote process
    pid=fork();
    if(pid==0) { // child process
        execvp("./target",argv);
        return 0;
    } else if(pid==-1) {
        puts("Error creating child process!");
        return 0;
    }
    printf("This process: %d\n",getpid());
    printf("Created process: %d\n",pid);
    local[0].iov_base=buf1;
    local[0].iov_len=10;
    local[1].iov_base=buf2;
    local[1].iov_len=10;
    remote[0].iov_base=(void*)0x10; // address 0x10
    remote[0].iov_len=20; // 20 bytes
    nread=process_vm_readv(pid,local,2,remote,1,0);
    if(nread==-1) {
        printf("process_vm_readv error: ");
        switch(errno) {
            case EINVAL: puts("EINVAL"); break;
            case EFAULT: puts("EFAULT"); break;
            case ENOMEM: puts("ENOMEM"); break;
            case EPERM: puts("EPERM"); break;
            case ESRCH: puts("ESRCH"); break;
        }
        return 1;
    }
    printf("%ld bytes read\n",nread);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check out `strerror()`. Also, check the manpage, it explains pretty well what the reasons for the fault could be. If I were you, I'd first try it without forking, i.e. to read from the same process. At least, that avoids having to communicate valid addresses between the two processes, which is probably what you failed to do.

Comment: What makes you think that your child process has something at address 0x10? The error looks sensible. There is nothing there so it returns EFAULT.

Comment: @UlrichEckhardt The advice of using `strerror()` and considering how addresses work has been helpful. I am indeed getting a `Bad address` error, and this is making it a bit easier to narrow down the problem. @Art After taking the address of the variable in the `target` program, I get a really big value, not just 0x10, so it was a good idea to check that out. My initial assumption was that the 0x10 would be relative to the start of the `target` program's ram. Do you have any links to where I can read about the proper way of doing this?

Comment: Use `pmap -x $PID` to explore valid virtual address ranges.